# How add unique elements in Redis for custom classes or objects

Tags: python, redis

I want to add unique elements to Redis list. But the elements which I am storing in Redis are custom class objects. I have class Message and it has fields like message_id, message_body, message_timestamp, message_from, message_to etc. Here uniqueness is based on message_id. So Redis list must all the message objects with distinct message_id. I am using "redis" from python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want a list? sounds like you need a Hash. Make the message id your key and a json representation of your object your value.

```
client.hset('my_key', obj.message_id, json.dumps(obj))
```

If you want to iterate the objects later you can use [HSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) or HGETALL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this out. Actually, my current project has list implemented..so looking for the solution so that no need to change current implementation.